# SQL Select : Return a specific value in an else condtion

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario in postgres where I wish to perform a simple division of two fields.

I wish the answer returned to be a 1 if the answer is less than 1

```
SELECT a/b AS Answer

6/4 = 1.50
4/6 = 0.66
4/4 = 1.00
```

For example if the calc above were used I would like the SQL to return a value of 1 for the second calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE-WHEN`

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ans < 1
            THEN 1
        ELSE ans
        END AS answer
FROM (
    SELECT a / b::REAL AS ans
    FROM num1
    ) t
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/37d61/2)

or

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN a < b
            THEN 1
        ELSE a / b::REAL
        END AS answer
FROM num1
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/37d61/3)

Comment: `GREATEST` can be used,like this `SELECT GREATEST(a/b::real, 1)  answer from num1`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE table testdata (a int,b int);
WITH data AS (
    INSERT INTO testdata VALUES (6,4),(4,6),(4,4)
)
SELECT a,b,
  CASE WHEN a/b::REAL < 1 THEN 1
   ELSE a/b::REAL
  END
FROM testdata;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GREATEST(a/b, 1) AS Answer
```